# TensorFlow cross-entropy on tutorial

Tags: tensorflow

I was just going through the `TensorFlow` tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#deep-mnist-for-experts).

I have two questions about it:

1. Why does it use the `cost function with y_ * log(y)`? Shouldn't it be `y_ * log(y) + (1-y_) * log(1-y)`?
2. How does `TensorFlow` know how to calculate the `gradient` of the `cost function` I use? Shouldn't we have a place somewhere to tell `TensorFlow` how to calculate the `gradient`?

Thanks!

Comment: The gradient descent function is already programmed. You can dig in the source code to find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. When y = 1 or 0, you can use y_ * log(y) + (1-y_) * log(1-y), but when y is one-hot encoding, y=[0 1] or [1 0], we use y_ * log(y). In fact, they are the same.
2. Everything is a graph in TensorFlow including your cost function.

[image]

So each node knows their operation and local gradient. Tensorflow uses backpropagation (chain rule) to compute the gradient using the graph.

Comment: Why are all the graphs so small? I can't read any of them, including this one. Can I download an SVG or something?

Comment: @BSeven I just wanted to show "cost" is a node in the graph. You can run TensorBoard to get better graphs.

Comment: Also you can view graphs in IPython notebook as done [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/deepdream/deepdream.ipynb) (look for show_graph)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov - That's helpful. Thanks. And the part about "image generation techniques implemented with TensorFlow for fun" is very interesting.

Comment: Thanks Sung, really appreciated! I'm new to both TensorFlow and Python and I didn't realise y_ was actually a vector with [0 1] or [1 0], I thought it was 0 or 1. I haven't seen TensorBoard either and I'll check it out.